# Cant change the name of the link in a website?

Tags: php

I have downloaded the source code for a web application and I am feeling awful because there is this part of the website where there are some links you click.(Obviously).For example one of the links is Job seeker's sign in,like you can see in the figure.For the life of me,I can't find a way to change the name of that link.I want to change the name from Job seeker's sign in to Jobby's sign in .In the source code for the theme of the page I have

```
<a href="<?php echo JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER?>"><?php echo $label['classic_job_seeker_signin']; ?></a> |
```

Problem is ,there is no candidate folder in the website source!

[image]

Comment: This is where the links label is stored is: `$label['classic_job_seeker_signin']`.

Comment: Might be a handy manual http://www.jamit.com/JamitJobBoard3.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices :

The proper one : find where is defined this var `$label['classic_job_seeker_signin']` and change this value

**Or** you can change this value before printing the link like this :

```
<?php $label['classic_job_seeker_signin'] = "Jobby's sign in"; ?>
```

Comment: I love you.I am literally crying right now and hugging my cat.I have tried to find where that  variable is defined for three hours now and I couldn't find it but I  was hesitant to post here.

Comment: Haha you're welcome ! You can thanks @arkascha too in the comment :)